# Escaping stand alone &'s in XML, but ignoring &amp;

Tags: xml, html-escape-characters

I can potentially have an XML document with "&" and also the proper "&amp;" mixed in the document.  So for example:

```
<foo>
    <bar>Tom & Jerry</bar>
    <bar>Garfield&Friends</bar>
    <bar>Fred &amp; Barney</bar>
</foo>
```

I can't do a straight up find and replace of & since that would screw up the "Fred &amp; Barney" line.

Is there any way to replace the &'s that aren't part of a proper &amp; ?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: I am using C# language

Comment: Looks like this Regex solved it from the post referenced by Progman:
&(?!(?:#\d+|#x[0-9a-f]+|\w+);)